# Custom Posts not showing in archive page

Tags: php, wordpress

I currently have a custom post type of Episode with a taxonomy of podcast.  When i run the following loop on my archive page i am seeing that I have 149 posts

```
<?php          
    $args2 = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1000,
            'post_type' => 'episode',
            'podcast' => 'my-episodes',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
            );
        $posts = get_posts($args2); 
        $count = count($posts); 
        echo $count; 
?>
```

However, when I'm running this variation of the loop on my archive.php file (copied from the wordpress.org page), i am only getting 130 posts

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <small><?php the_time('F jS, Y'); ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></small>

    <div class="entry">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>

    <p class="postmetadata"><?php _e( 'Posted in' ); ?> <?php the_category( ', ' ); ?></p>

 <?php endwhile; else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

The loop is saying that my most recent entry was from the 5th, however i have been creating posts on a regular basis over the last few days.  Are there any tests I can run to see why the most recent posts are not showing up on the archive page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the dashboard of the site  per the recommendation of Tom here is what I was able to find

- The site has a plugin called WPML activated.  This allows the site to create content in multiple languages.
- When the plugin is initially activated, it will ask for the site's native language and apply that to the *existing* posts and custom posts.  This way if you were on an englsih version of the site you would see content ABC while on a spanish version you would see content XYZ.
- There is a separate section inside of a custom post that allows you to make said custom post translatable.  **If this is not checked then your custom post will not display on any version of the site.**  The reason being (at least in my 5 minutes of research) is that because there is no language specified, it will not load on the language specific versions of the site

I have done two things to fix this:

1. I have added the ability to make the custom post translatable,
2. There is a setting that will allow you to display all content that is not translated on any version of the site as opposed to not displaying any content

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to be correct. Double check that the posts that are missing are published and not set as a draft/saved. Also check that your custom taxonomy and post types are correct for the query you are running.